# Imagemagick: Move image to float pixel

Tags: floating-point, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I would like to move an image to a floating point position, so that the 
imagemagick take care of simulating the non integer position.

What it does now is to round the coordinates.

So if I try:

```
convert ( -size 640x360 xc:black ) ( rose: -geometry +10.5+10.5 ) -composite image.png
```

I will get the result of:

```
convert ( -size 640x360 xc:black ) ( rose: -geometry +10+10 ) -composite image.png
```

Since I'm trying to create an animation moving an image frame by frame, the rounded coordinates makes the animation too jerky!

Tks in advance!
Néviton

Answer (score 0):

You will need to double the size of your working canvas to work in integers, then scale back to 50% at the end.

```
convert ( -size 1280x720 xc:black ) ( rose: -scale 200% -geometry +21+21 ) -composite -resize 50% image.png
```

Note the difference between `-scale` and `-resize`: -scale performs no interpolation (it is the same as -resize with `-filter box`; -resize interpolates pixels based on the `-filter` setting.  I used -scale for the rose: image because we don't want to introduce any degradation in this initial scaling-up of our working canvas, but used -resize for the final scaling-down because the interpolation effect is precisely what we are after to simulate motion.

Comment: I'll try that, but it will consume a lot more of the CPU!